# Stop browser from redirecting http post request to https

Tags: google-chrome, https, axios

I am using the NPM module Axios to make http requests to a server from a webpage on my localhost. The server url is using http but when I check the request in the browser dev tools, I see the URL in the request is being changed to https, thus failing. How can I prevent this redirect from happening? This is happening in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are running in `node.js` or in a browser?

Comment: Node.js is compiled and run in browser

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will always follow HTTP redirects, so a library like Axios will not be able to prevent this from happening. There is an [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932) on their GitHub explaining that this can't be fixed by them.

If you are running in `node.js` then you can prevent this from happening by setting `maxRedirects: 0` in the request config.

Comment: But why is it redirecting to https in the first place? Is this a known a restriction in Chrome? When I type the url in the browser directly it doesnt get redirected to https.

Comment: It may be being caused by Strict Transport Security (HSTS) in that case

Comment: I get "domain not found" when I try doing hsts query in chrome so I don't think that's it

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 headers: {
        scheme: 'http',
      },
```

Put that in your axios options. It forces the browser to send the request on `http` or `https` if set to any.
But you may need cross-access (CORS) allowed on the other side.
I hope this helps